# Intern / Selenium: chromedriver capabilities for automatic file download

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, intern

We are using [intern with chromedriver](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#local-selenium) for functional tests. I need to download something and then analyse the downloaded file.

In the `intern.js`[configuration file](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#runner-config) I set

```
capabilities: {
  ...,
  ChromeOptions: {
    prefs: {
      "download.prompt_for_download": false,
      "download.directory_upgrade": true,
      "download.default_directory": "/home/user/Documents"
    }
  }
}
```

I indeed do not have a donwload prompt anymore and the file gets downloaded, but

- files are saved to `~/Downloads` and not to the folder I specify
- After setting `"download.prompt_for_download"` back to `true` I still do not get a prompt anymore, even after restarting chromedriver, rebooting, removing all capabilities or even manually changing in the chrome settings.

See also:

- [chromedriver capabilities](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)
- [chrome automatic download capability](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1192)

---

#### Solved

Typo: replace `ChromeOptions` with `chromeOptions`.